# String vibration patterns

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, string, vibrations, normal-modes

Sometimes when you pluck a string on a stringed instrument, the string turns into what looks like a nearly stationary loop with a semi-transparent middle.

Sometimes, the loop doesn't appear stationary, but you can see a wobbling "string" inside it.

Why is it that sometimes one happens and sometimes the other?

Answer (score 1):

When the instrument is plucked, it can go into one of the vibration modes below, depending exactly where and how it's plucked

[image]

from this webpage

https://www.earmaster.com/music-theory-online/ch03/chapter-3-2.html

The appearance then depends on which mode occurs.

Comment: This is the first step towards an answer, but it ignores (1) the inharmonicity caused by the elastic stiffness of real strings and (2) the fact that the strings in a real stringed instrument can vibrate in 3D not 2D, and because of unsymmetrical real boundary conditions (which are not idealized rigid constraints) there will be *pairs* of vibration modes with similar (but not identical) frequencies and mode shapes. Note, part (2) is critical to understanding the playing technique of *acoustic* classical guitars.

Comment: @alephzero Good point, maybe the OP will see this comment